# Dynamically publish attributes in Polymer

Tags: attributes, polymer

Is it possible to publish new Polymer component attributes at runtime?

```
<polymer-element name="dynamic-attributes">
    <template></template>
    <script>
        Polymer('dynamic-attributes', {
            ready: function(){
                var attributes = new Thing().getAttributes();
                this.publishAttributes(attributes); // imaginary method         
            },
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

---

More info...

I'm writing a component lib that wraps [Seriously.js](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js).

Here is an example of the ideal implementation.

```
<seriously-graph linear>
    <seriously-source>
        <img src="images/pencils.jpg">
    </seriously-source>
    <seriously-effect type="pixelate" pixelSize="{{pixelSize}}"></seriously-effect>
    <seriously-effect type="blur" amount=".5"></seriously-effect>
    <seriously-target width="411" height="425"></seriously-target>
</seriously-graph>
```

I have a work-around that uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect attribute changes. It works, but then I have to find a solution for serialization and make property getters/setters. It feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel (Polymer), and was hoping there was a built-in method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/phestermcs/bd631c5822d192dbbb3d) that does what you're looking for. Basically, it dynamically creates a *concrete* `<polymer-element>` for an effect the first time it's used, and then swaps the *generic* instance with a dynamically created *concrete* one, copying any binding declarations in the process. The source would be:

```
<seriously-effect type="blur" amount="{{someAmount}}"></seriously-effect>
```

But with Inspect Element, you'd see:

```
<seriously-effect-blur amount="{{someAmount}}"></seriously-effect-blur>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by assigning an attributes object to *publish* node. See https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attributes for details.

Your method must return an object of attributes:

```
Polymer('dynamic-attributes', {
  publish: (new Thing()).getAttributes() || {}
});
```

Comment: This is part of the component definition, and only runs once. I need a solution that will let me set the attributes after components are instantiated. I added some more info to the question to clarify.

Comment: I am not familiar to MutationObserver and aspects of Seriously.js, but there is inner solution to detect attribute changes in Polymer: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers

Comment: Default attributes values may be defined in publish node and then accept new values by using element.setAttribute('name', 'value')

Comment: Change watchers only fire for published attributes. And publishing attributes does a lot more than just listen for changes. It defines property getters and setters, handles serialization, and maybe some other stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a global array and use it as attribute?

```
<polymer-element name="app-globals" attributes="values">
  <script>
    (function() {
      var values = {};

      Polymer({
         ready: function() {
           this.values = values;
           for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; ++i) {
             var attr = this.attributes[i];
             values[attr.nodeName] = attr.value;
           }
         }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<app-globals id='myDynamicFunctions' someFunction someOtherFunction></app-globals>

<script>
    //then define it
    document.$.myDynamicFunctions.values.someFunction = function(){...}
</script>
```

I am not quite sure what you are looking for, this might give you a hint...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it won't work for what I need to do. Each instance of the effect components need to be able to have unique attribute values